# Show integer as binary sequence (java)

Tags: java, binary, long-integer

Say I have an integer number: `11728322732`
how can i convert it to a string according to its byte representation, i.e `11100011000000001100000111110001` (32 bits \ 4 bytes \ integer)

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Here it is:

```
Long.toBinaryString(11728322732L);
```

Actually, `11728322732` is not an `Integer` but a `Long` (because it is greater than `Integer.MAX_VALUE`). So if you **really** want to convert this long to a 32-bits int (can't figure why actually), you could do:

```
Integer.toBinaryString((int)11728322732L);
```

Comment: Good answer, but that number is bigger than `Integer.MAX_VALUE`  ;)

Comment: @aliteralmind good one. Fixed it!

Comment: I use integers so Integer.toBinaryString(...) works just fine, thanks

Comment: Does anyone knows how can I convert a binary representation back to int ? for instance 11000000 to 192 ?

Comment: `Integer.parseInt("11000000", 2);`  (that means _"convert it from base 2"_)